# How to get the URL of a bottle.py dynamic route?

Tags: python, bottle

I just start to use bottle.py. Since my app is not deployed as site root. I am using get_url for the redirect code like this:

```
@myapp.route("/")
def index():
    redirect(myapp.get_url("/hello"), name=name)
```

For example if the application is deployed  to http//www.mysite.com/cgi-bin/myapp.py it will be successfully redirect to http//www.mysite.com/cgi-bin/myapp.py/hello

Now the problem is how can I redirect to a dynamic route? For example

```
@myapp.route("/hello/<name>")
def hello(name):
     .....
     return template(...)

@myaap.route("/")
def index():
   #How to redirect it to /hello/<name>?????
```

Now I want to redirect a page to route "/hello/" but get_url is not accepting it. It doesn't work with dynamic route.

I am not going to write my own "my_get_url" to deal with it. I think everybody that has deployed bottle application to a non-root site should already have faced and solved the problem.....

Any comment is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `redirect(myapp.get_url("/hello%s" % name)` ??

Answer (score 1):

You should use both a name and a route, and refer to the route by the name.

For example:

```
@app.get(path="/admin/customers/single/messages/system_messages/delete/<message_id:int>",
         name="admin.customers.single.messages.system_messages.delete",
         _run_functions_before=[
             user_has_permissions([UserPermissionForCustomer.super_user_access])
         ]
         )
def delete_system_message(resources, message_id):
    """
    @param resources:
    @type resources: 
    @param message_id:
    @type message_id: int
    @return:
    """
    system_messages_logic = SystemMessagesLogic(resources)
    system_messages_logic.delete_system_message(message_id)
    return list_system_messages(resources)
```

In the above example, you can refer to the route like the following:

```
 redirect(app.get_url("admin.customers.single.messages.system_messages.delete", message_id=message_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given the route as

`@myapp.route("/hello/<name>")`

the redirect doesnot work as

`redirect(myapp.get_url("/hello"), name=name)`

rather it should specify the entire url as `/hello/somename/`

That is if trying to pass the value of a variable, `name` as in the code,  it can be written as

```
@myapp.route("/hello/<name>")
def hello(name):
     .....
     return template(...)

@myaap.route("/")
def index():
    redirect(myapp.get_url("/hello/") + '/' + name)
```

Comment: redirect(myapp.get_url("/hello/%s" % name) doesn't work. It will raise an error: "No route with that name". The first arg of get_url looks like has to be a "route name".

Comment: try something like `redirect(myapp.get_url("/hello/")+name)`
See the edited answer